# Drive spreadsheet, wrapping link

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, word-wrap

I'm trying to find a way to make Google Spreadsheet wrap a link, and showing the content in many lines, just like microsoft excel works:
[image]

I've found nothing so far on how to implement this, which should be used very often I believe.
Here's how the same excel works imported to Google Spreadsheet:

[image]

In the google spreadsheet I selected "Wrap text" but it only wraps it, hiding the overflow of it, however I can't see the whole link.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: If it was possible to manage to still have the correct link, then I guess it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the contents of the cell in order to display wrapped text, you could use an additional column with a formula like this to insert spaces after certain characters so that the url can wrap:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"&","& "),"/","/ "),"?","? "),"#","# ")
```

You should keep the original URL around though, since the resulting value will no longer be a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheets only wraps text where there is white space or hyphens. It will not wrap in the middle of a word the way Excel does. There's no way around this I'm afraid.

Comment: That's what I already know haha, I'd like to know if there's a script or hopefully a workaround :) , I was surprised to find this problem as this must be something commonly needed

Comment: No workaround. Not unless you are willing to change the Url to add spaces to it.

Comment: If there's any automated way to do so, I guess it'd work (for example adding a space after each &, for every text in that column)